# How to change label fonts when resizing using tablelayoutpanel in C#

Tags: c#, fonts, tablelayoutpanel

I am using tablelayoutpanels in my c# forms to resize the form to suit different screen sizes. The resizing works well but when labels are resized, the text on the label remains the same and may not fit in the label if the screen is smaller. Is there a way to change the font automatically to the text fits in the label size?
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font.FontFamily, panel1.Font.Height, FontStyle.Regular);
```

You keep the font family property and chenge the font size of the principal panel